# Kendo ui grid pagable size changing after refresh the grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, pagination, kendo-grid, page-refresh

I have kendo grid with custom search form . In my search form i have submit and reset button .
If something search then the grid will update with searched filter datasource, and click reset the grid will get refresh with new datasource.
My problem is without reset If i change the pagesize value 10 to 20 and i click reset the grid ..then the grid pagesize change into 20 to 10 ...If i click next page then the pagesize remain 20 for second page, 10 for first page

How do i resolve this ? Any idea ?
My code for pageable:

```
           pageable: {
                pageSizes: [10,20, 30, 50],
                buttonCount: 5,
                messages: { 
                    itemsPerPage: "Items per page",
                    first: "First",
                    previous: "Prev",
                    next: "Next",
                    last: "Last",
                }
            },
```

Comment: You need to persist user preferences, have a look here: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/persist-state

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that now you are [changing the Kendo UI DataSource instance](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-setDataSource) to which the Grid is bound. If this is the case, then you have two options:

- instead of changing the dataSource instance, only change the data in the [current dataSource instance](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#fields-dataSource) by using its [`data()`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-data) method. You may also need to [clear the filter programmatically](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-filter).
- if you prefer to change the DataSource instance, then [obtain the page size](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-pageSize) from the old instance and [set it to be the same in the settings](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-pageSize) of the new DataSource instance.

Answer (score 0):

As [dimodi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3086237/dimodi) stated

You may need to clear the filter and set your pageSize

Example:

```
var grid = $("#GridName").data("kendoGrid");

grid.clearSelection();

var pagesize = grid.dataSource.pageSize();
grid.dataSource.query({
    sort: { field: sortField, dir: sortDescOrAsc },
    page: 1,
    filter: {},
    pageSize: pagesize
});
```